# Why Adsense ads don't show up more than once in each page?

Tags: adsense

I have a News website. 
Adsense ads don't show up more than once in each page.
I've done Adsense troubleshooter suggestions. and It seems everything is ok...

Website address is : http://akhbaralalam.com

It seems after google adsense crawls the page for next requsts ads don't show up.
But I can't find out what is the problem with my pages...

Maybe useful : When I put a random argument like "/?123" to the end of URL, ads are showing.

akhbaralalam.com -> ads don't show up

akhbaralalam.com/?123 -> ads show up

Is there any suggestions or something?

Can you please investigate?

Comment: Your topic belongs on: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How to port it there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way I realized what the problem is...

I had a funny mistake:
On pages with more than 3 Ad units it may result to disappearing all the ads.

also I added privacy policy to the footer of the site. In google adsense guids they said it's necessary to have a privacy policy including some certain topics like cookies...